# Worker interrupted by message

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to learn what will happen if web worker is sent message by it's parent while it is processing something?

It will finish executing current part of code and then react to message or executed code will be interrupted, message handled and interrupted code will continued?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it goes on a queue. And it receives the oldest unhandled message in that queue as soon as it becomes available.

It shouldn't interrupt anything.